# BEFORE and AFTER triggers, FOR EACH ROW and FOR EACH STATEMENT triggers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to sql and in particular to postgresql, and I'm studying it for university, but I'm having trouble understanding when I should use AFTER TRIGGERS instead of BEFORE TRIGGERS and when I should make my trigger a FOR EACH ROW TRIGGER or a FOR EACH STATEMENT TRIGGER.

From what I understood, every time the constraint has a count, a sum, an average or depends on a property related to the whole table I should use an AFTER TRIGGER with FOR EACH STATEMENT but I'm not sure and honestly I'm pretty confused.

Do you have any tips for when I should use each type of trigger, or how to understand when I should choose one over the others?

Thank you!

Comment: Asking you question in all caps is not a good idea

Comment: Please read some documentations and try out and ask a more specific question if this doesn't help. An example: https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-sql-triggers/

Comment: Read [Create trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) and [plpgsql trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). If you want an in depth description see [Triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html).

Comment: @JonasMetzler: a description for SQL Server is hardly useful if Spooky is using Postgres

Comment: Exactly, thus the focus will be on the ideas of the different triggers instead of DB-type-specific syntax which is much more important.

Comment: @JonasMetzler: SQL Server doesn't have row level triggers, so the question which one to use can't be explained in the context of SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You use a `BEFORE` trigger `FOR EACH ROW` if you want to modify the data *before* they get written to the database.

You use an `AFTER` trigger if you need the data modifications to be already done, for example if you want to insert a row that references these data via a foreign key constraint.

You use a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger if you need to deal with on its own, and `FOR EACH STATEMENT` if the actual rows processed don't concern you (e.g., you want to write an audit log entry for the statement) or you want to access the modified data as a whole (e.g., throw an error if someone tries to delete more than 10 rows with a single SQL statement).

Comment: But for example if the condition that I have to model through the trigger refers to a count on the table in which I am doing the INSERT or UPDATE table, or an average or a sum on the table, is it safe to assume that due to the fact that those are "global informations" of that table I should use a statement level trigger or not? I understood the fact that the main difference between row level and statement leevl is the number of times the trigger is activated and the order in which they are executed but are there specific cases when I should use a row level or statement level?

Comment: This cannot be answered in general. It aleays depends on the use case. I would say that anything that is too complicated should not be coded as trigger. Gather some experience, and you will get a feeling when triggers are appropriate and when to use which one. I have never encountered a statement level trigger in a real-life database. That does not mean that they are worthless or don't exist, only that they are rare.